# Is there a way to conditionally concotanate and add two rows while creating a third row that combines elements?

Tags: r, loops, string-concatenation

Suppose I had the following

| Item | Ingredients | Cost | Item ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza | Cheese | $.01 | 001 |
| Pizza | Flour | $.04 | 001 |
| Pizza | Tomato | $.04 | 001 |
| Bread | Flour | $.04 | 003 |
| Cookies | Flour | $.07 | 004 |
| Sandwich | Flour | $.04 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Cheese | $.01 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Meat | $.10 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Lettuce | $.01 | 002 |

How would I create new rows that concatenate the ingredients and add up the total item cost in Cost all while leaving item and item id alone?

My main issue is the placement of the new rows as I would want them to be on top of the individual ingredients. I can't wrap my head on creating a loop for this. Is there an elegant solution?

| Item | Ingredients | Cost | Item ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza | Tomato Cheese Flour | $.13 | 001 |
| Pizza | Cheese | $.01 | 001 |
| Pizza | Flour | $.04 | 001 |
| Pizza | Tomato | $.07 | 001 |
| Bread | Flour | $.04 | 003 |
| Cookies | Flour | $.04 | 004 |
| Sandwich | Flour Cheese Meat Lettuce | $.16 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Flour | $.04 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Cheese | $.01 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Meat | $.10 | 002 |
| Sandwich | Lettuce | $.01 | 002 |

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   reframe(Ingredients = str_c(Ingredients, collapse = ' '), 
  Cost = str_c('$', sum(readr::parse_number(as.character(Cost)), na.rm = TRUE)), 
       .by = c('Item', 'Item ID')) %>%
  bind_rows(., df1 %>% mutate(Cost = str_c("$", Cost)) %>%
  arrange(Item)
```

Comment: You could add `distinct()` at the end to get rid of duplicate rows for single-ingredient `Item`s.

Comment: I feel like I need to say that cost is not a string but numeric. Should I make cost a string as a work around?

Comment: @BmorenoGS Now, it should work in both cases

Comment: it works, but I now get duplicates of bread and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(Ingredients = str_c(Ingredients, collapse = " "),
            Costs = str_c("$", sum(as.numeric(str_extract(Costs, "(?<=\\$).*"))))) %>%
  mutate(rowID = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(., df %>% mutate(rowID = row_number()+1)) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  arrange(Item) %>%
  select(-rowID)
```

Comment: What if costs are not strings and are in fact numeric?

Comment: if there's the dollar sign, they cannot be numeric. But even if they were, the solution wol still work.

Comment: I keep trying to run your code, but I get Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: I can only help you when you post **reproducible data**, using for example `dput(head(YOURDATAFRAME))`